# CreateWindow Scrollbar alignment issue

Tags: winapi, scrollbar, alignment, createwindow

Consider the following partial code.  My problem is that the Scrollbar is not aligned with the rectangle.  I get a rectangle and a scrollbar with a large gap between the two.  I figured I could experiment and find out what the "offset" is and just put that in but I'd like to understand why the scrollbar apparently does not seem to honor the coordinates.

```
hCDC = GetDC(hCWnd);
bkgBrush = CreateSolidBrush( BGColor );
SetMapMode( hCDC, MM_TEXT );
SelectObject( hCDC, bkgBrush );
Rectangle(hCDC, VTRect->left, VTRect->top, VTRect->right, VTRect->bottom);

iHThumb = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXHTHUMB);
iVThumb = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVTHUMB);

hInstance = NULL;

if( hWndVertScroll )
DestroyWindow( hWndVertScroll );

hWndVertScroll = CreateWindow(
            "Scrollbar",
            (LPSTR)NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBS_VERT | SBS_RIGHTALIGN,
            VTRect->left,VTRect->top,VTRect->right,VTRect->bottom-iVThumb ,
            hCWnd,
            NULL,
            hInstance,
            NULL);
```

To correct for the gap, I'd invoke the CreateWindow call using the following:

```
hWndVertScroll = CreateWindow(
            "Scrollbar",
            (LPSTR)NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBS_VERT | SBS_RIGHTALIGN,
            VTRect->left,VTRect->top,VTRect->right - 100 ,VTRect->bottom-iVThumb ,
            hCWnd,
            NULL,
            hInstance,
            NULL);
```

but I don't understand why VTRect->right - 100 is required to but the scroll bar up against the right side of the Rectangle.  Note that I did try VTRect->right - iHThumb but I still have a gap albeit a smaller one.

Screen shot of the red rectangle and scrollbar and the gap between the two:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> VTRect->left,VTRect->top,VTRect->right - 100 ,VTRect->bottom-iVThumb

The arguments you pass to CreateWindow() with these values are x, y, *nWidth* and *nHeight*.  Width and height, not right and bottom.  Fix:

> VTRect->left, VTRect->top, VTRect->right - VTRect->left, VTRect->bottom - VTRect->top